# CSS div is larger than border of the div its within

Tags: html, css, flask

As it stands, I'm trying to write a form which is responsive for the device that is displaying the webpage. However, I have an issue that, for the styling, I can't get the div which holds the form content to be within the main dic, which I proved with adding borders to the div. I know there is probably a simple answer, but I can't figure it out.

As viewed from a mobile device, this is what I currently see, with a div that is not centred within the page.

[image: Image of the div within the div]

And this is what the content div looks like

[image: div content]

This is what the new_user css is (the div within the div)

```css
.form.new_user {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 230pt;
            max-width: 270pt;
            border-color: #3e3e3e;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-style: solid;
            padding: 5pt;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600pt){
            .form.new_user {
                min-width: 100px;
                max-width: inherit;
            }
        }
```

And then also the css for the content div

```css
.content {
    padding: 7pt;
    margin: 7pt;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

HTML code below.

```
<body>
<div class="content">
<div class="form new_user>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

And also I have the css for body as

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML code or make a snippet so that we can see your result?

Comment: @SatoTakeru I have done that for you, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because..

> By default in the CSS box model, the width and height you assign to an
> element is applied only to the element's content box. If the element
> has any border or padding, this is then added to the width and height
> to arrive at the size of the box that's rendered on the screen.

Just add `*{box-sizing: border-box;}` You can find more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.form.new_user {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            min-width: 230pt;
            max-width: 270pt;
            border-color: #3e3e3e;
            border-width: 1px;
            border-style: solid;
            padding: 5pt;
        }
.content {
    padding: 7pt;
    margin: 7pt;
}

        @media screen and (max-width: 600pt){
            .form.new_user {
                min-width: 100px;
                max-width: inherit;
            }
        }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="content">
<div class="form new_user">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```